# When creating a new Gradle project in Eclipse Neon, why does the Gradle wrapper version default to an older version of Gradle?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, gradle-eclipse

I'm new to Gradle (but I'm familiar with Ant and Maven), and I tried creating a new Gradle Project with Eclipse Neon.

For the `Gradle distribution` option, I chose `Gradle wrapper` as [Gradle documents](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) seem to suggest this is preferred (and it is the default). However, when I click on `Next`, I see that:

1. the Gradle version being used is 2.14.1 instead of 3.2.1 (which is what was installed when I ran `brew install gradle`); and
2. I get a warning that some functionality won't be available because I'm using this older version.

So…

1. Should I not use the `Gradle wrapper` option and instead use `Specific Gradle version`?
2. Or, should I configure Gradle/Eclipse somehow to use the correct Gradle version, and if so, how?
3. Or, is there something else I should do, and if so, what?

---

Here is the output from `gradle --version`:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-11-22 15:19:54 UTC
Revision:     83b485b914fd4f335ad0e66af9d14aad458d2cc5

Groovy:       2.4.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_102 (Oracle Corporation 25.102-b14)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.12.2 x86_64
```

Comment: I'll add that the option I've decided to go with for now is #1 — I chose Specific Gradle version, 3.2.1. It seems to be working, but I haven't done too much with the project yet.